# Is is possible to create date-ranged in-app subscription in Apple and Google Plays stores?

Tags: ios, google-play, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

We are currently offering a variety of premium plans on our app using in-app purchases and **not** Subscriptions. We have a 4 months plan and 1 year plan when user pays from the start (he can cancel at any-time by contacting us and our back-end manages the plans so after the period of the plan has ended he is downgraded automatically) and we want to switch this mechanism to monthly payments subscriptions for better revenue reasons.

It looks as (at least on Google Play) that we can define the billing period by weekly, monthly, etc, but the period of the subscription is still *indefinit* by meaning of time.

Are subscriptions are "for life" until user cancels it? How does it work?

Is it possible to create a fixed 4 months or 1 year subscription that is paid monthly until its finished automatically? How can we define that a subscription needs to end after exactly 4 months since user first purchase it? (It should also be auto-renewal month by month in that period).

If this is not possible, can we somehow create an indefinit subscriptions and "cancel" the subscription on iOS and Google Play stores for the user without him knowing? (from back-end or clients)

Also, what happens if user to buy a different subscription while he is already in one? Should he cancel and also then buy?

Thanks for any clarification. The official guidelines by both companies are no so clear.

Comment: Multiple questions combined in one, You can not have 4 month subscription plan where user is billed every month for 4 months and then downgrades automatically, when u use renewable subscriptions you can specify the duration of subscription like 1 month / 4 month etc in that case user will be charged 24 hours before the subscription period ends once per cycle of subscription until user cancels the subscription him/herself from iTunes connect account. What you need is non-renewing subscription or consumable subscription

Comment: In case of non-renewing subscription, once the subscription period runs out user will have to renew it manually, so you can create a IAP with 4 month as subscription period and then once user crosses that period he will not have access to certain content/feature of your app (down graded) unless he renews it manually. As per your second question of what if user buys multiple subscriptions, in case of auto renewable subscriptions (am not sure of other models please check) you can create subscription groups

Comment: one can purchase only one product in one subscription group, for example I have IAP for 1 month and 4 month in one subscription group and I buy 1 month and the subscription period is not yet ended if I go ahead and try to buy 4 month now iTunesConnect will give you error stating u cant buy this thing because u already have purchased one belonging to same group :) hope that solves your problem,

Comment: As mentioned above you can also use consumable subscription where user can buy the same subscription multiple times once they use up their purchase, while showing product description u can show as this product will give u access to 4 months but then head ache is on backend/client to maintain purchase time state and then finally implementing logic to prevent user from accessing features/content once product is used up. I believe non-renewing subscriptions makes more sense in your case

Comment: Thanks, @SandeepBhandari. My main concern is to be able to create a subscription which is paid monthly for a specific period of time (3 months, 4 months, etc.) and afterwards it will finish automatically. I think from what you said that this is not possible with renewable subscriptions. It this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by consumable subscription (I'm sorry, more of an Android developer than iOS one). Does it the equivalent for a regular in-app purchase like in Google Play? A one-time charged item?

Comment: Yes one time charged but gets used up by user example assume you have a zombie shooting game you wanna offer special kinds of bullets on fire it will kill all zombies in screen in one shot, if you wanna offer a pack of 30 such bullets for 30$ you create consumable IAP product for 30$, once user shoots all 30 bullets he will have to re purchase the product again. So this user can buy as many times as possible but as name suggests once you bought the product u consume it

Comment: read https://www.raywenderlich.com/147629/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscriptions-tutorial for more detail